# Layer image on top of plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot different colors in nine rectangles on top of an image. The easiest solution I've come up with is to plot the rectangles and then layer a transparent background image over it. However when I try to do this the image always appears behind the triangles.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

image_link = r'image.png'
dx = 301
dy = 225
xy0 = (68, 33)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.add_patch(Rectangle(xy0 , dx, dy)) 
im = plt.imread(image_link)
implot = plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

I figured since I'm adding the image AFTER my rectangle it'd be shown on top, but no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New code:

```
image_link = r'image.png'
dx = 301
dy = 225
xy0 = (68, 33)

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.add_patch(Rectangle(xy0 , dx, dy)) 
im1 = plt.imread(image_link)
implot1 = plt.imshow(im1, alpha=0.75, zorder=1)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.add_patch(Rectangle(xy0 , dx, dy)) 
im2 = plt.imread(image_link)
implot2 = plt.imshow(im2, alpha=1.0, zorder=1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: No, the rectangle box is still on top of my image. The idea is that you're meant to see the image even though we've put a rectangle on it

Comment: New code added...  I used `alpha` and `zorder` options...